# tomcat error while starting

Tags: tomcat, liferay

java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

Getting the above error when I start the tomcat 5.5.x server in myeclipse.

Actually I have taken the check out and compiled it on my 32 bit windows machine.
Now when I took the back up of my tomcat and checkout and try to start in windows 7 64 bit I am getting error.
Can any  one suggest what is the issue.Below is the complete stack trace.

```
usage: java org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina [ -config {pathname} ] [ -nonaming ] { start | stop }
log4j:WARN No such property [maxFileSize] in org.apache.log4j.FileAppender.
Loading jar:file:/D:/liferay-portal-5.2.3/tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/system.properties
27 Sep 2014 12:20:21,013 INFO org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[Catalina].[localhost].[/].log():653 [main] - Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Loading jar:file:/D:/liferay-portal-5.2.3/tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/portal.properties
Loading file:/D:/liferay-portal-5.2.3/tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes/portal-ext.properties
Loading jar:file:/D:/liferay-portal-5.2.3/tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/portal-impl.jar!/captcha.properties
27 Sep 2014 12:20:29,884 INFO com.liferay.portal.util.PortalImpl.<init>():252 [main] - Portal lib directory /D:/liferay-portal-5.2.3/tomcat-5.5.35/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/lib/
27 Sep 2014 12:20:36,350 INFO com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.ServerDetector.getServerId():104 [main] - Detected server tomcat
Sep 27, 2014 12:20:39 PM com.sun.portal.container.service.ServiceManagerContextListenerImpl contextInitialized
INFO: PSC_CSPCS001 : Started initializing ServiceManager
Sep 27, 2014 12:20:39 PM com.sun.portal.container.service.ServiceManager addService
INFO: PSC_CSPCS004 : Service added, Name: com.sun.portal.container.service.CoordinationService, Implementation: com.sun.portal.container.service.coordination.impl.CoordinationServiceImpl
Sep 27, 2014 12:20:39 PM com.sun.portal.container.service.ServiceManager addService
INFO: PSC_CSPCS004 : Service added, Name: com.sun.portal.container.service.CachingService, Implementation: com.sun.portal.container.service.caching.impl.CachingServiceImpl
Sep 27, 2014 12:20:39 PM com.sun.portal.container.service.ServiceManager addService
INFO: PSC_CSPCS004 : Service added, Name: com.sun.portal.container.service.ClientCachingService, Implementation: com.sun.portal.container.service.caching.impl.ClientCachingServiceImpl
Sep 27, 2014 12:20:39 PM com.sun.portal.container.service.ServiceManager addService
INFO: PSC_CSPCS004 : Service added, Name: com.sun.portal.container.service.DeploymentService_Local, Implementation: com.sun.portal.container.service.deployment.impl.DeploymentServiceLocalImpl
Sep 27, 2014 12:20:39 PM com.sun.portal.container.service.ServiceManager addService
INFO: PSC_CSPCS004 : Service added, Name: com.sun.portal.container.service.ContainerEventService, Implementation: com.sun.portal.container.service.coordination.impl.ContainerEventServiceImpl
Sep 27, 2014 12:20:39 PM com.sun.portal.container.service.ServiceManager addService
INFO: PSC_CSPCS004 : Service added, Name: com.sun.portal.container.service.PolicyService, Implementation: com.liferay.portal.portletcontainer.PolicyServiceImpl
Sep 27, 2014 12:20:39 PM com.sun.portal.container.service.ServiceManagerContextListenerImpl contextInitialized
INFO: PSC_CSPCS002 : Finished initializing ServiceManager
Sep 27, 2014 12:20:39 PM com.sun.portal.portletcontainer.impl.PortletContainerContextListenerImpl contextInitialized
INFO: PSPL_PCCSPCPCI0003 : Starting PortletContainer 2.1
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:295)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:433)
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

Comment: There are others that give 200 lines stacktraces (which is typically too much), but a single line from a stacktrace is definitely not enough to identify the cause. Please give more information. Also, is there any reason why you're using this ancient version of tomcat? My first reaction is: "Upgrade!"

Comment: The version is the one that we need to use and iys working fine on one system having xp with 32 bit and 4gb ram.i will provide the entire stack trace

Comment: Added the complete stack trace.Please suggest

Answer (score 0):

The key line here is

```
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
```

My first educated guess is that you're out of PermGen memory. There's plenty of information on how to deal with it all over the internet (including [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=PermGen)), so I won't repeat the explanation here.